# Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.8.3 syntax and error highlighting problem after updating from v 17.64

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vs-community-edition

I have a problem with Visual Studio intellisense & error highlighting after moving to a new PC and forced to install a updated version of VS 2022 community.

I have been using VS community version 17.6.4 for a long while with a solution I'm working with. I then updated VS community to version 17.8.3 on a new PC. There is no ability to rollback the version. Since doing so the intellisense and error highlighting (squiggle underline) of errors does not work like it used to. These two pics attached show an example of the type of difference using the same deliberate syntax error introduced, and how in V17.8.3 there is very little that highlights errors.
The lack of proper intellisense error highlighting occurs any where in the project.
Any errors introduced produce a build error in the output window, but no highlighting or links to the source of the error in the code.

It is a WPF C# project/solution targeting net framework 4.8

I have tried everything I can think of to fix the problem.
I have installed/repaired VS many times.
I have deleted hidden directories like the "vs" folder in the solution.
I have disabled/enabled everything in tools-options related to c#/Texteditor/intellisense multiple times.
I have checked one by one the options and project settings between each of the two versions of VS and they are the same.
I have reset the VS settings to default multiple times.
Both PC are running Windows 11 pro.
I have installed VS community 2022 17.9.0 preview v2.0 and it has the same problem.
I have installed VS professional 30 day trial version and it has the same problem.

I feel the problem must be a compatibility issue in the project itself, but I have no idea how to try and isolate it.

Can anyone suggest how to tackle this problem or suggest a solution.
Thanks for any help.

I have attached two images to illustrate the big difference between the two VS versions.

Just a reminder, I deliberately introduced a syntax error at the top line with Data Set, to force Vs to show the difference in highlighting between the two versions of VS. This is just one example to show most recent V17.8.3 misses out a lot of error highlighting.

I also censored parts of the images not relevant.

[image: VS version 17.6.4]
[image: and VS version 17.8.3]

Comment: I don't understand why my question was negged. It seems clear and detailed about what I am asking.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-2022-1783-Syntax-Highlight-broken/10535255